# How to enable Aura for this class

Tags: salesforce, lwc

```
 public List<SelectOption> getYearList(){

    Integer year =  Date.Today().year();
    String s1=string.valueof(year).right(2);
    Integer Year1= Integer.valueof(s1);
    List<SelectOption> YearListOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    YearListOptions .add(new SelectOption('','YY'));
    for(Integer i=Year1;i<=Year1+8;i++)
    {
       string j=string.valueof(i);

        YearListOptions .add(new SelectOption(j,j));

    }
    return YearListOptions ;
}
```

I tried but Getting error like AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of List

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have Changed this but anyone have any suggestion or comments please feel free to add

```
@AuraEnabled   
public List<String> getYearList(){
    Integer year =  Date.Today().year();
    String s1=string.valueof(year).right(2);
    Integer Year1= Integer.valueof(s1);
    List<SelectOption> YearListOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
    List<String> yearValueList = new List<String>();
    YearListOptions .add(new SelectOption('','YY'));
    for(Integer i=Year1;i<=Year1+8;i++)
    {
        string j=string.valueof(i);
        YearListOptions .add(new SelectOption(j,j));
    }
    for (SelectOption sO : YearListOptions){
        yearValueList.add(sO.getValue());
    }
    return yearValueList ;
}
```

Comment: this is correct that if you are accessing apex method from lightning component that needs to have `@AuraEnabled` annotation. However, what looks strange is that you get the error as _AuraEnabled methods do not support return type of List_. AuraEnabled method do support return type as List but not Set which is not the case here. Can you share some more details/ whether this issue has resolved? @Tech Skill

Comment: @Arin Thanks for your response, Yes this issue has been resolved and I have posted the working code too. (answered May 29 at 7:07)